# Specifying left join conditions using rails include syntax

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Is there a more railsy way to do this query in rails 3?

```
scope :unblocked_on_invite, joins(
  "LEFT JOIN blockers 
    ON blockers.member_id = members.id 
    AND blockers.type = 'InviteBlocker'").where("blockers.id IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use :include it will perform an automatic INNER JOIN. As far as LEFT JOIN goes you are doing exactly what you should be doing. The only way I can see to make this more railsy is to write it like this:

```
scope :unblocked_on_invite, joins(
  "LEFT JOIN blockers 
    ON blockers.member_id = members.id 
    AND blockers.type = 'InviteBlocker'").where(:blockers => nil)
```